# Как работает тест глубины в OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Как работает тест глубины OpenGL? Например, мне нужно, чтобы выводилось только пересечение квадрата и круга. Как мне это сделать в коде? А если нужно получить пересечение нескольких фигур, и рисовать потом в этом пересечении?

Answer (score 0):

Тест глубины работает очень просто:

1. Поддерживается **буфер глубины**, в котором для каждого пикселя на экране (опустим АА и скейлинг для простоты) есть 1 значение - глубина этого пикселя. От 0.0 до 1.0.
2. Обычно **буфер заполняется в начале кадра** значениями максимальной глубины (1.0).
3. При рендере пикселя, его расчетная **глубина сверяется** с глубиной записаной в буфере, с использованием активного правила сравнения (меньше, меньше или равно, больше, больше или равно, всегда истина). Если сравнение возвращает истину, то пиксель добавляется в буфер цвета и значение его глубины попадает в буфер глубины (заменяя старое). Если ложь - ничего не происходит. Правило сравнения можно менять между вызовами отрисовки.

Всё. А дальше уже вы сами попробуйте написать свой алгоритм пересечений.