# Как работать глубиной OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Есть тут схожий вопрос, [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710238/Как-работает-тест-глубины-в-opengl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710238/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2-opengl)
но я хотел уточнить. Вот мне допустим надо что бы одна фигура перекрывала другую! То есть мне надо свои алгоритмы прописывать? Это все делается в шейдерах? Или есть в OpenGL инструменты для работы с глубиной?

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на схожий вопрос и не добавляйте "Я учу OoenGL.." и подобное в вопросы, потому что это лишний шум, отвлекающий от содержимого. Тут все что-то учат, новички, которых не надо бить палками, и так далее

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710238/Как-работает-тест-глубины-в-opengl

Comment: Используйте кнопку править

Comment: Хорошо понял вас

Comment: `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`.

Answer (score 1):

Инструмент есть, называется Z-Buffer. Перекрытия он вам посчитает сам.